# How can I tell if my Pi is underpowered if I don't use the GUI?

Tags: raspbian, power

I rarely, if ever, use the GUI on my Pi devices. I develop for it from my laptop workstation.

In the UI, there's an annoyingly terrifying icon** that pops up for this condition, but how can one tell if a Pi is under-powered if only used in headless (console-only with no immediately direct visibility of the console itself) mode?

** - ok a bit extreme

Comment: @SteveRobillard Thanks. Although it would be trivial for me to look the info up, figured it's worth having a proper answer here on the board.

Comment: I agree, I am working my way through the linked forum thread for some additional ideas on logging etc. I also assumed this arose from the comment on the previous question

Comment: @SteveRobillard You'd be correct in assuming it was spawned from the last thread. I really like your efforts on a better system for acknowledging this potential issue, because honestly, my Pi's are often in a closet and I never look at them. I've been focusing on a Perl wrapper for PI (wiringPi and custom code for ICs), and lately, an automated test/build system for said project. I never look at the hardware unless I crash some of them and have to hard-reboot ;)

Comment: If you update the answer with anything further, I'll try to adapt my question to your answer. If you have any suggestions/insight into any re-wording, let me know so everything lines up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When under powered the B+ Pi2 and Pi3 will flash the red (power) LED. When properly powered the LED is lit steadily.

There is a long raspberrypi.org [forum thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=82373) on the inner workings of this feature.